# Generate FORM from Model

Tags: doctrine, symfony-1.4

I am new in Symfony 1.4.I just make a new table named as `User` and after that I run below 2 commands

```
$ php symfony doctrine:build-schema
$ php symfony doctrine:build --model
```

This command creates there classes named as `User.class.php`, `UserTable.class.php` and `BaseUser.class.php` in `Symfony->lib->model->doctrine` directory
Now I want to make a CRUD for this table `User`.
I know this is generated from this command

```
./symfony doctrine:generate-module frontend author Author
```

for this I need a form that is actual problem. Now I want to make a from for this table only.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

Just Do :

```
$ php symfony doctrine:build-forms
```

Check this documentation here :

http://symfony.com/legacy/doc/reference/1_4/en/16-Tasks#chapter_16_doctrine

It'll give you a good idea of the code that you can generate from the command line.

Comment: actually this commands override existing forms that's why I don't want to use this I just want to generate form for only one model

Comment: It overrides only the symfony's core forms classes, where you are not supposed to work in. You must work not inside the "base" directory, but in the upper one